# Don't understand why ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded occurs

Tags: python, json, object

I'm getting this following error

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

My json data is valid, i changing the JSON file encoding to utf-8, but still didn't work, this is my code :

```
f = open(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+"/test.json", 'w+')
data = json.load(f)
pprint(data)
```

And this is my test.json data:

```
{"X":19235, "Y":19220, "Z":22685}
```

Comment: For testing, try replacing `json.load(f)` with `f.read()` - make sure it's loading the file properly

Comment: You're opening your file in write mode with 'w+'. Remove that and try again.

Comment: @idjaw - good call, i missed that :)

Comment: Actually, your test data file is empty. "w+" truncates the file. Take a look at test.json and you will see it no longer has anything in it.

Comment: ^^ Exactly. That's *the* error you get when you have an empty file and try to perform a `json.load` in Python 2.

Comment: its `json.loads` not `json.load`

Comment: @levi [json.load](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) is perfectly valid. `load` expects a file object while `loads` expects a string. So, to use `loads` one would have to do a `read()` on the file object to get the string. For what the OP is doing right now, the problem really is that they are opening the file in write mode and emptying their file. Their usage of `load` is correct here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let's confirm your json data is valid emulating the content of your file like this:

```
import json
from StringIO import StringIO

f = StringIO("""

{"X":19235, "Y":19220, "Z":22685}

""")

try:
    data = f.read()
    json.loads(data)
except:
    print("BREAKPOINT")

print("DONE")
```

The script is printing only `DONE`, that means the content of your file is a valid JSON, so if we take a look to your script:

```
f = open(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+"/test.json", 'w+')
data = json.load(f)
pprint(data)
```

The main problem of your code is you're using `w+` write mode, which is truncating the file (you should use reading mode) so the file object is not valid anymore. Try this:

```
f = open(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+"/test.json", 'rb')
data = json.load(f)
pprint(data)
```

or this:

```
f = open(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+"/test.json", 'rb')
data = json.loads(f.read())
pprint(data)
```